# Why is the input() function returning None?

Tags: python, input, jupyter-notebook

So I am using Jupyter notebook and when I run the code

```
name = input(print('What is your name?'))
```

The code will produce the output:

```
What is your name?

None []
```

Since I cant copy and paste the rectangle that comes when using the function input(), lets asume the brackets represent that rectangle. Then say you write `John Doe` in the box, it will then show `NoneJohn Doe` Why is the word None shown next to the name and the box? How do you remove it? Thanks

Comment: you have to `return name`

Comment: I forgot to add print() to the example above, but do you mean use retrun instead of print?

Comment: Why are you using print inside input?

Comment: Do `name = input(What is your name?')` instead. You are printing the return value of `print`. But input already displays the prompt.

Comment: @GuyIncognito - Um, that's quite clearly the mistake we need to have him fix.

Comment: @tdelaney That's why I asked why he's using it. I wouldn't need to ask if it wasn't a mistake.

Comment: Sorry I did not know you were not supposed to use print inside input, thank you.

Comment: @GuyIncognito - Why not just give the solution then? The answer to your question is that he thinks he's supposed to use print.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to prompt the user to type his/her name and then print out the name? 
if so, try this:

```
name = input('What is your name?')
print('Your name is '+ name)
```

Also with this in mind.
Input takes a prompt string as its argument, which it will print automatically, but print returns None; it is this that gets printed by input. Your code is equivalent to:

```
name = print(...) # prompt == None
ans = str(input(name))
```

Instead, use str.format to build the prompt and pass it straight to input